# Need ORM for JOIN MongoDB collections

Tags: python, mongodb, orm, mongoengine

I have to create script in Python which like parameters has name of first collection and name of second collection ( MongoDB collections in db ). I need to perform JOIN between those two collections on some passed names of fields ( I don't know structure of collections and need to be generic enough ). I looked at ORMs like Ming, MongoKit, MongoAlchemy, MongoEngine and minimongo 
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tools.html#orm-like-layers
Does anybody have experience with any of those ORMs and JOINS, any advice, example ?

Comment: I guess you may have to look at NoSQL solutions that have direct links between records: Riak and graph databases like Neo4j. But they wont help when you literally _" don't know structure of collections"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very unlikely a MongoDB mapper/ORM solution would allow JOIN-like behaviour since it's a feature associated with relational databases and has no place in NoSQL based ORMs (for example, there's no way to do them consistently in MongoDB). Frankly, if the ORM does implement JOIN like behaviour for you I would probably consider it a design flaw.

What's stopping you from implementing the requested functionality yourself in your py script?

Comment: The collections are very very big, so I am afraid to stay without memory. I can probably do this in chunks but it will be very slow, I hooped that there is maybe more elegant solution

Comment: If something working with a non-relational database claims to be ORM, I'd be very suspicious to begin with since the author doesn't know what the "R" in "ORM" stands for in the first place.

Comment: @Damir You don't have to read the entire thing in memory first. Do it in batches. What could a mapper do in terms of memory use that you can't?

Comment: @Wooble Very good point actually. ORM is such a common term for a mapping solution that I didn't even think of that either ;)

Comment: @RemonvanVliet Wooble Thanks guys, I'll read in parts and join in application. I know that in Mongoid ( ORM for Ruby for MongoDB ) there is support for joins and relations has_many, that is reason why I thought that Python can have the same thing.

Comment: The behavior you're looking for, and what exists in ORMs like Morphia , is called "References". It is not a join, per se, but is more like a helper to lookup objects by ID in a separate query, typically in a lazy way.

Comment: @Wes True, that's probably as close to a JOIN as I've seen a mapper go. Not sure if I'm comfortable with "hidden" lazy fetches though.

Answer (score 1):

A Join is not what you're looking for, as you can't really do joins. What is typically available in the drivers or ORMs/ODMs (such as Morphia for Java and Mongoid for Ruby) is a Reference, where you have an ID or list of IDs that point to objects in another collection. Then, there is typically a helper function to dereference (run another query for the reference), so that you can bring back that contained object without having to do it explicitly.

There is actually a feature in the python driver that allows this to be done automatically. Here's an example (updated to unit test--other example was old):
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/test/test_dbref.py